# How to seed rand() in Spring Boot JPA query

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql, random-seed

In a Spring Boot JPA query, when adding a seed to function 'rand' I'm getting "org.hibernate.QueryException: function takes no arguments: rand"

```
@Query("select mt from MyTable mt order by rand(4711)")
```

My database supports both rand functions, with and without parameter.

Is there a way to make that JPA query work?

Comment: can you give a try it with `nativeQuery = true` , ie: `...order by rand(4711),nativeQuery = true")`

Comment: @namila007 yes, a native query should work, but my question is about how to do it with JPA/JPQL